# partial sum of square free integers

Tags: summation, analytic-number-theory

Im trying to compute the following

$\sum_{\substack{q \leq x \\ q \ square free}} q^{-1/2}$

I know that $\sum_{\substack{q \leq x \\ q \ square free}} 1 = \frac{6}{\pi^2}x + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$

and

$\sum_{n \leq x } n^{-1/2} = 2\sqrt{x}+c+\mathcal{O}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\Big)$ where $c$ is some constant. Is there there any way to combine the two to get a result for the first summation?

Comment: Sure, and the result is (not really a surprise) $\frac{12}{\pi^2}\sqrt{x}+O(\ln x).$

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorVector. Can you explain how you got this answer?

Comment: It's not very obvious for me. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define $$c(x)=\sum_{\substack{q \leq x \\ q \ square free}} 1,$$
the sum is $$\sum_{n\le x}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}(c(n)-c(n-1))=\sum_{n\le x}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)c(n)+\frac{c(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}},$$ that's called partial summation. I think it should be easy to move on from here.

Answer (score 0):

We present  by way of  enrichment an evaluation using  analytic number
theory which  provides a closed  form as  a target of  more elementary
methods.   Observe  that the  Dirichlet  series  of the  indicator  of
squarefree numbers is given by

$$L(s) = \prod_p \left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)
= \prod_p \frac{1-1/p^{2s}}{1-1/p^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}.$$

Observe furthermore that

$$\frac{1}{n^{s+1/2}} = \frac{n^{-1/2}}{n^s}$$

and hence the Dirichlet generating function for this problem is

$$M(s) = \frac{\zeta(s+1/2)}{\zeta(2s+1)}.$$

The  dominant simple  pole here  is at  $s=1/2$ and  we may  apply the
[Wiener-Ikehara
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem),
getting for the asymptotics

$$\frac{x^{1/2}}{1/2}
\mathrm{Res}_{s=1/2} \frac{\zeta(s+1/2)}{\zeta(2s+1)}
= 2\sqrt{x} \frac{6}{\pi^2} = \frac{12}{\pi^2} \sqrt{x}.$$

The next terms from the underlying Mellin transform integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
M(s) \frac{x^s}{s} \; ds$$

originate with the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function.